# Modifying displayed keyword on kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it there a way to change the string/keyword being displayed on a specific dashboard?

Lets say that in a certain display I have the following keyword being shown.

**[Scan 1] Extended HTTP Methods found**

Is it there a way so this keyword appears as

**Extended HTTP Methods found**

Without changing the actual document within elasticsearch with an update query?

Answer (score 0):

as it stands currently, changing the X-axis and Y-axis, is not possible. However, if you can create the same visualization in `Vega`, it will be flexible to change the respective axis.

I used the default visualization given by `Vega`, and I was able to change the specific axis title as follows:

[image]

The query:

[image]

After that, I saved the visualization and added it in a dashboard.

It may be done as follows:

1. Create or use an existing dashboard.

If you are creating a new select the following option (`Add An Existing`):

[image]

2. Search for the object

[image]

3. It will be added to this dashboard as follows:

[image]

Let me know if you have any issue, I will be glad to help.